# Scan multiple email id from table - DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using `@awspilot/dynamodb` to fetch data from a customer table where `customer_id` is the primary key.

I need to get customer id based on multiple `customer_email`.

```
dynamodb
    .table('bc_customer')
    .select('customer_id')
    .having('email').eq('test@gmail.com')
    .scan(function( err, data ) {
        console.log(data);
  });
```

The above code allows me to pass single email id, is there any way to search on multiple email id?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB supports [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), which allows you to get data from one and only one partition (i.e. one partition key), or [scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) which returns every item in the table (i.e. a full table scan).

If you know the partition keys to query, it will be faster to do multiple queries and combine your result set. If you don't care about performance or you are happy with the speed (bear in mind a scan will scale poorly as your table grows) you can use a scan.

Note that above you are actually doing a scan, and so you are not using your partition key as an index.

A query would be like this:

```
DynamoDB
    .table('bc_customer')
    .where('email').eq('test@gmail.com')
    .query(function(err, data ) {
        console.log(err,data)
    })
```

And a scan (I think - the [awspilot documents](https://awspilot.github.io/dynamodb-oop/#scan) are not too clear) should be something like:

```
DynamoDB
    .table('bc_customer')
    .having('email').eq('test@gmail.com')
    .having('someattribute').eq('something')
    .scan(function( err, data ) {
        console.log( err, data )
    })
```